# What screen resolutions should we test on when developing for mobile devices?

Tags: web-development, mobile

If I wanted to make a mobile version of a website, what are the most common screen resolutions that I should be testing on?

Comment: This question might also be appropriate on http://sqa.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ethel, thanks, I am not a member of that site yet. New SE sites are popping up so fast its hard to keep track.

Answer (score 9):

According to my Android Market stats the testing screens should be as follows:

- The most common is (still) **480x320** resolution of pre-4 iPhones and most of middle-range Android/Nokia devices
- Followed by **320x240** of the low-end Android (HTC Wildfire, HTC Tattoo...) and older Nokia Symbian devices
- Followed by **800x480** of the new Nokia and Android devices (HTC Desire, Galaxy S, Nexus One...)

Since the most avid mobile web consumers are iOS users, I also recommend testing on the iPhone 4 resolution (**960x640**) and the iPad resolution (**1024x768**).

Testing for lower resolutions isn't all that useful, since most people that buy such low-end phones, don't use mobile web all that much.

Comment: Your last paragraph only holds true if your market *isn't* Africa or India.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your definition of "mobile". ;-)

I would test at the following resolutions (and their rotated equivalents since many devices support rotation, given below in PORTRAIT orientation):

- 240*320
- 320*480  (iPhone w/o Retina)
- 640*960  (iPhone w/ Retina)
- 800*480  (Android; from @Mavrik's answer)
- 768*1024 (iPad)

Can you make a design that will work great on all the available resolutions? Yes, but it'll take some work and probably some hacks for each size and browser type. At the moment, I'm only going to worry about modern phones in my mobile development, and since a modern smartphone usually has a good webkit browser, I'll target that (since it should have decent CSS/JS/HTML support). Older phones will be much more handicapped in what they will support, and so you may end up having to have several versions of your site in order to support old phones.

I agree with @Mavrik in that designing for the lower resolutions isn't really that useful anymore since you're going to have fewer and fewer devices in that class. But it doesn't hurt to see how painful things look -- just know that the ROI on making a site work on older phones isn't at all good.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like if I make sure it works at a minimum of 480 pixels wide, most users will be able to see all content without side scrolling.

Comment: @John Isaacks I would look into Media Queries with CSS3 if you're going down the path I think you're going. You'll be able to develop one stylesheet for all of the sizes you're seeing.

Comment: @melee, good point, I have used that in the past.

Answer (score -2):

So as we know,  **iPhone ** is still king, and it uses [960-by-640-pixels](http://blog.demandware.com/blog/bid/13266/Smartphone-Screen-Resolution-and-Size-Driving-Mobile-Commerce)..

But there are a lot of small variations, such as the Motor. Droid  at 854*480. There is not set rule.

On old phones(circa '08) it appears to be [640 by 200/360/480 & **320*240**](http://sender11.typepad.com/sender11/2008/04/mobile-screen-s.html)

Comment: Hi Adel, welcome to Programmers.SE! We're looking for answers that go into a little more depth than a one liner and a link: can you elaborate and provide any expert insight into the problem?

Comment: Actually, only the iPhone4 is 960x640. All other previous versions are still 480x320.